# Low memory error using SD card

Tags: arduino-uno

I called HTTP web service on Arduino Uno, now i am trying to store the data in SD card. But as soon as i compile the program, it shows LOW MEMORY error and no data stored in SD card.
Any one can help?

Comment: Use a board with more memory. Both those operations use a lot of RAM for buffers.

Comment: Please suggest the board.

Comment: How do you copy the data? It's very unlikely that your UNO can copy all the data at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Arduino mega. It has more memory 8 KB RAM, 256 KB flash memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use properly  kind of variables for example if u r using Int in a value can would  use byte of try to put some serial.println(F("wherever  you can print "))  for running  on sram instead of  stack memory.

Comment: Tried to put serial.println(F(" ")) but still same problem.

Comment: If it still gives the same problem, why is this answer accepted?